# Inserting string before end tag of an XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

```
<elem1>
<elem2/>
<elem2 id="1234567"/>20,000 Leagues Under the Sea</elem1>
```

I've been trying to insert strings from list `x`, if the id provided matches with a list item using `lxml`. The problem being, I can't seem to find a way to do make it go **right before the end of parent tag** `</elem1>`.
Example string:

```
<elem3><elem4>book, item</elem4></elem3>
```

Desired output:

```
<elem1>
<elem2/>
<elem2 id="1234567"/>20,000 Leagues Under the Sea<elem3><elem4>book, item</elem4></elem3></elem1>
```

.tail function can do the thing I want, but on the opposite side of the tag, not inside it. Simply appending string to .text of the element technically works, but it can't display it due to, I imagine, `<elem2/>` tags at the beginning in some cases, and after such case it usually stops working in subsequent iterations of a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `count()` the number of elements in the document, and `insert(where, what)` after that:

```
books = """<elem1>
  <elem2/>
  <elem2 id="1234567"/>
  20,000 Leagues Under the Sea
</elem1>
"""
doc = etree.fromstring(books)
newbies = """<elem3>
<elem4>book, item</elem4>
</elem3>
"""
elems = etree.fromstring(newbies)


destination = int(doc.xpath('count(//*)'))
#you need the int() because the output of count() is a float
#also remember that python counts from zero
doc.insert(destination,elems)
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output:

```
 <elem1>
  <elem2/>
  <elem2 id="1234567"/>
  20,000 Leagues Under the Sea
<elem3>
<elem4>book, item</elem4>
</elem3></elem1>
```

Comment: Should `.parse()` work the same way in this case as `.fromstring()`? Because I'm working with entire files and equivalent of `doc = etree.parse('books.xml')` doesn't seem to work with `doc.insert()`. I'm getting:
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: @Thorwyn. Yes, it should, though the boilerplate is a little different, something like: `tree = etree.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()`

Comment: Alright, I'll be trying it out, thanks